# Big databases architecture for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, architecture, sqlite

When creating a mobile app that needs to store big amounts of data to be queried and used offline I normally use sqlite3 performing bulk inserts, but when it comes to content's modifications I have performance troubles to delete or update rows.

Over the past year, I have seem some developers opposed to creating apps' databases using foreign keys, alleging this would increase performance, but I have never tried it myself as this seems like bad practice to me.

What would be the best approach in this occasion?

Comment: I found inert/update performance pretty poor if you forget to use transactions. Make sure you're wrapping your bulk inserts with transactions and you'll have to insert _a lot_ of data to make it too slow.

Comment: I do wrap them using transactions, this really helps a lot.

Comment: Have you analyzed the query plans? Maybe you need better indexes on the tables.

Comment: Yes, we have even redesigned our entire ER diagram to suit faster queries.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259265/sqlite-bad-performance-with-on-delete-cascade?